# concatenate a variable name with a number

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have many fields. (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, etc.)

I want to insert an image in a field when a user clicks on it.
If I have to rely on my special (and I mean that in an Olympic way) non-algorithmic process below, I'll never finish.

Any help doing this the right way would be appreciated.

```
<span onclick=Flag(1)>Field 1 <%=field1%>< /span>
<span onclick=Flag(2)>Field 2 <%=field2%>< /span>
<span onclick=Flag(3)>Field 3 <%=field3%>< /span>
<span onclick ..... < /span>

<script>
sub flag(x)
 Select Case x
  case 1
   field1="< img src="checkmark.png">"
   field2=""
   field3=""
   field4=""
  case 2
   field1=""
   field2="< img src="blue1.png">"
   field3=""
   field4=""
  case 3
   field1=""
   field2=""
   field3="< img src="blue1.png">"
  case ...
 end select
end sub
</script>
```

Comment: I don't write any ASP but could you just place the matching images in an array and add them that way? So you would have something like `['checkmark.png','blue1.png',...]` and apply that to the fields.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like your trying to call a vbscript sub routine through an onclick method which you can't do. 
You can acheive this with just javascript though

```
<script>
var flds = ["checkmark.png","blue1.png","blue2.png"];
function Flag(x) {
    document.getElementById("field"+x).innerHTML = "Field " + x + " <img src='" + flds[x-1] + "'>";
}
</script>

<span id="field1" onclick="Flag(1);">Field 1</span><br />
<span id="field2" onclick="Flag(2);">Field 2</span><br />
<span id="field3" onclick="Flag(3);">Field 3</span>
```

**What's Happening:**

The first line within the script tag declares an array and adds all the image names into it.

When a span is clicked it calls the javascript function Flag which passes a number into it.

The corresponding span to the number passed into Flag is updated with an image extracted from the array. (You extract 1 from x in the array because an arrays index starts at 0 not 1)

Comment: Believe it or not, if you're using Internet Explorer you can embed VBS in the page instead of JavaScript! [Strange but true](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=20991&seqNum=6)!

Comment: Well I never new that. But just because you can doesn't mean you should :)

Comment: I completely agree - it's only compatible with IE browsers ... of course! ;o)